# Return multiple values to an Oracle java function using types

Tags: java, oracle

Unable to return multiple values to an Oracle function from java using an Oracle type

I've created an oracle type & function to call a java method with the simple purpose of swapping the values of the two fields I have in the Oracle type.  Everything compiles just fine, but when I execute the function in Oracle I just receive the original type values.

In Oracle:

```sql
create or replace type swapper_in as object (
a varchar2(20),
b varchar2(20) );

create or replace function swapstring (s swapper_in) return swapper_in
as language java
name 'swapperstring.swap(java.sql.Struct) return java.sql.Struct';
```

```java
public class swapperstring
{
  public static java.sql.Struct swap( java.sql.Struct i )
  {
    Object[] attribs=null;

    attribs = i.getAttributes();
    attribs[0] = attribs[1];
    return i;
  }
}
```

```sql
declare
  s swapper_in
  o swapper_in
begin
  s := swapper_in('String One', 'String Two');
  dbms_output.put_line( s.a );
  dbms_output.put_line( s.b );
  select swapstring(s) into o from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line( o.a );
  dbms_output.put_line( o.b );
end;
```

Output:

```
String One
String Two
String One
String Two
```

Since I set the first attribute to equal the second in the java code I would expect the output to be String Two for both fields in the output.  But it appears it is returning the original object unmodified.

How do I modify attributes of a java.sql.Struct or create a new object with modified attributes?